# How to check if aspecified object exists in a given list of object or not with java

Tags: java

I am using java 11 and  i want to check if a object exist in list of object i use

```
   List<MenuDTO> menuDTO=new ArrayList<>();
   MenuDTO menu=menuData.findByIdMenu(menuItemDTO.getMenuid());

   if(menuDTO.contains(menu)){
                    menuItemResult.add(menuItemDTO);
                    menu.setMenuitems(menuItemResult);
   }
```

But it return always false even the list contain the element

Comment: Do you have `equals` and `hashCode` methods implemented for `MenuDTO` object?

Comment: no, Should i have equals and hashCode to use contains?

Comment: @sokida yes, you do; otherwise an object is only equal to itself (x == y).

Comment: Okay, Thank you so much for ur help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but maybe this can help:

```
List<MenuDTO> menuDTO=new ArrayList<>();
MenuDTO menu=menuData.findByIdMenu(menuItemDTO.getMenuid());
boolean doesExists = menuDTO.stream().anyMatch(menuElement -> menuElement.getMenuId() == menu.getMenuId());
if(doesExists){
    menuItemResult.add(menuItemDTO);
    menu.setMenuitems(menuItemResult);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Java collections `contains` use object `equals` methods to determine if specified object is in the collection, so you need to implement it for objects that you use in collections.
Here is some guide on how to implement `equals` and `hashCode` methods on objects:

[Java equals() and hashCode() Contracts](https://www.baeldung.com/java-equals-hashcode-contracts)